# Flutter - Unable to maintain zoom on Transform.scale widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to build some zoom functionality into the flutter camera package for my app. Currently I am able to use the zoom feature by wrapping the `CameraPreview` widget in a `Transform.scale` and a `GestureDetector`. However whenever I am zooming in it is not maintaining the zoom. Currently it is snapping back to 1.0 scale when letting go after pinching and zooming.

Is there something I am doing wrong here? I am able to maintain the scale using the onDoubleTap function but not using the onScaleUpdate function.

Here is my code:

```
                  ClipRect(
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: LayoutBuilder(builder:
                          (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onDoubleTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              scale = 4.0;
                            });
                          },
                          onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
                            print(details.scale);

                            setState(() {
                              scale = details.scale;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Transform.scale(
                            scale: scale,
                            child: AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                              child: CameraPreview(controller),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  )
```

Comment: see https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/matrix_gesture_detector - it has 5 examples on how to use it

Comment: @pskink i'm getting an error when running flutter packages get: Running "flutter packages get" in ontrac_incident_reporting...     The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.


Because ontrac_incident_reporting depends on matrix_gesture_detector >=0.0.2 which requires SDK version >=2.1.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1)
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: whats your flutter version? whats the output of  `flutter --version` command?

Comment: Application finished.
OTL12019:ontrac_incident_reporting callumclift$ flutter --version
Flutter 1.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5391447fae (3 months ago) • 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
Engine • revision 7375a0f414
Tools • Dart 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

Comment: so get it from github and change `environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"` to `environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0-dev.9.4 <3.0.0"` in its `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: @pskink - nice package - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/matrix_gesture_detector

Comment: @anmol.majhail thanks, do you by any chance know where i can find what dart version is used by particular flutter version?

Comment: @pskink - nah! sorry - i guess they haven't mentioned it anywhere. -

Comment: @psink i've managed to change it but now i'm not entirely sure how to use it with regards to my initial issue. I've managed to enable the zoom on the camera preview now however it is rotating as i zoom in and i don't know how to grab the scale value for use late in cropping the image

Comment: MatrixGestureDetector(shouldScale: true,
                                onMatrixUpdate: (Matrix4 m, Matrix4 tm, Matrix4 sm, Matrix4 rm) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    notifier.value = m;
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Transform(transform: notifier.value, child: AspectRatio(aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio, child: CameraPreview(controller),),)
                            )

Comment: check [transform_demo2.dart](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/transform_demo2.dart) - it does not rotate, also you have `tm`, `sm` and `rm` - three matrices that are only translated, scaled and rotated

Comment: Tried to change it and now I cant get the screen to move at all: MatrixGestureDetector(clipChild: false, shouldScale: true, shouldRotate: false,
                              onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
                                matrix = MatrixGestureDetector.compose(matrix, tm, sm, null);
                                notifier.value = matrix;
                              },
                                child: Transform(transform: matrix, child: AspectRatio(aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio, child: CameraPreview(controller),),)
                            )

Comment: does `matrix` in `transform: matrix` changes at all? tried to `print(matrix)`? where do you have `AnimatedBuilder` like in [transform_demo2.dart](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/transform_demo2.dart)? did you run that demo? does the center box moves and scales?

Comment: I/flutter (25083): this is the mstrix
I/flutter (25083): [0] 14.500248584322676,0.0,0.0,-3093.1542036776873
I/flutter (25083): [1] 0.0,14.500248584322676,0.0,-5882.308435522056
I/flutter (25083): [2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
I/flutter (25083): [3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0

Comment: I tried to incorporate parts of the demo into what I already have, without using AnimatedBuilder so i'm guessing I need that for this to work?

Comment: you can use `setState` too - basically you have to rebuild it - without it the whole thing will be static

Comment: ok i've got it working with the animated builder, however a couple of things, is there a way to prevent the widget from moving? all I need is the ability to zoom not to move the camera around. Also is there a way to allow zoom only from the centre point of the camera preview?

Comment: ok if you want **only** zooming (without moving) and **only** from center point then forget about  `MatrixGestureDetector` - use normal `GestureDetector` instead - i thought that you want scale & drag feature

Comment: This comes back to the original issue i was having, I am able to zoom using the gesture detector but whenever i take my fingers off the screen the zoom is resetting back to normal. Do you know a way to maintain the zoom? i'm using setState in the onScaleUpdate but this is not updating the scale in the Transform.scale widget (see my original post) appreciate your help thus far @pskink

Comment: sure i know the way to maintain the zoom, no only the zoom but also translation and rotation: see https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart#L136 there is `scaleUpdater` varaible that keeps the current scale factor